Discord is banned in my country; Is it possible to still acess it in Ubuntu without using VPNs?
I've been using Opera browser and its free VPN to access Discord
since my country banned Discord. 
Recently I changed my PC to Ubuntu Linux,
and I am wondering if I can modify my internet or the Discord app itself
so I can access it easily.

Opera is available for Ubuntu, too. If that is not an option, have you considered one of the popular commercial VPN providers?

Free vpns overall too slow with my already slow internet and i cant afford paid ones.
I am new to linux and I was just wondering if there is a easier and convinient way to solve this problem

Hang on. "I've been using Opera browser and its free VPN..." but you now want a solution without using a VPN? That would preclude installing Opera browser and its free VPN on Ubuntu, surely?

If it is just blocked by DNS, you could change your DNS servers to cloudflare or google, or use DoH, or do a lookup from elsewhere and save it as a local host file entry.
If the IP address is firewalled then that won't help. You need a vpn.
You might be able to use Cloudflares free VPN service, if you're worried about performance: it is very quick. Called Warp or 1.1.1.1. But iirc they do use endpoints in your own country, so might not get you much further, depends how good at blocking your government are!

A website can be blocked in several different ways.
The most usual way is by DNS, that you can override accessing the website by its IP.
Instead of accessing https://www.somesite.com you can go https://162.159.136.232/ for example.
Edit: Another way, would be using a webproxy.
You can find tons of options in a simple search.

Actually, trying to access https via an IP address is expected to result in an error since the SSL certificate should be issued for a particular domain name - see SSL certificate warning when accessing site through IP address

And even if you ignore the certificate issues, this will fail on hosts relying on virtual hosts (that is to say, hosting several web sites on the same IP address).
